# VS 2012 SSIS package Invalid name

Tags: ssis

I am building a SSIS package and I get the following error:

```
Error   1   Error saving LWP_INT_EPRISM_EMPLOYEE_COMPENSATION.dtsx: 
The file name is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
C:\Users\SiveB\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LWP_INT_EPRISM-EMPLOYEE-COMPENSATION\LWP_INT_EPRISM-EMPLOYEE-COMPENSATION\LWP_INT_EPRISM_EMPLOYEE_COMPENSATION.dtsx
```

Anyone have an idea on why?  The file name is alpha characters and underscores _ only.

Comment: More info is needed to answer your question. What was your process that lead to this error?

Comment: I believe I have found the issue.  I use a template to start new SSIS packages and one of the event handlers writes to a log file in a folder which I did not have permissions.  Once I was granted permissions to this folder the error was resolved so this is a case of bogus error messaging.  There is nothing wrong with my dtsx file name.